# How to change Figures and Tables caption fontsize with IEEEtran?

Tags: captions, subcaption

For a conference submission I am using IEEEtran. I want to change the fontsize of caption for both figures and tables. By adding following code I am able to increase caption fontsize for tables but caption size of figures is not changing.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
{\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
{\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
{\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
{\footnotesize}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Part of the reason it is so hard to change IEEE captions is that IEEE doesn't want you to mess with them in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `caption` package and assign any font size to an optional setting `font` in its macro `\captionsetup` (see page 9 in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption)).

One thing though, `IEEEtran` already sets custom formatting for the floats and `caption` will  override it; for instance, `Fig.` is supposed to be left aligned while `caption` will cause it centred. Therefore, some additional settings need to be used. Another thing is they have set specific font for floats for a reason. You may want to  make sure they will accept custom changes.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{twolinetab}{#1#2\\#3}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize, skip=12pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[table]{format=twolinetab,position=top}

\title{The Title}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image}
  \caption{Example}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[2]

\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \caption{The Table}
  \begin{tabular}{l cc}
    Head & Val 1 & Val 2 \\
    \hline
    Row 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    Row 2 & 3 & 4
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindmathpaper\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]